# ConstraintLayout inside LinearLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have to programmatically add a view (whose root view can be anything) into `LinearLayout` but if that view is a `ConstraintLayout`, it won't work as expected. Why is this happening, because according to my understanding, a child view must work regardless of what its parent view is. How do I make this work?

Problem is very simple and but I am not able to find any question addressing this problem.

I am attaching screenshots to show the distorted view:

**ORIGINAL VIEW** _____________________ **VIEW AFTER ADDING INSIDE LINEAR LAYOUT**

[image] _______ [image]

And here is the code:

```
override fun setContentView(view: View?) {
    val toolbar = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_toolbar, null, false)
    titleView = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView

    val finalView = LinearLayout(this)
    finalView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    finalView.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    finalView.addView(toolbar)
    finalView.addView(view)
    super.setContentView(finalView)
}
```

I am overriding the Activity's `setContentView` function.

Comment: did you try explicitely set the LayoutParams when doing finalView.addView(view) ? You might also give it a weight of 1 so that it occupies all the remaining space. **EDIT**: actually, I'm pretty sure LinearLayoutParams.weight=1 is what you want

Comment: Weight? Should I really try it? Because weight has nothing to do with the fact that why `ConstraintLayout` is acting funny inside `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @mbonnin man you beauty! It worked. Not the weight thing but explicitely setting `LayoutParams` when addingView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, there was nothing wrong with `ConstraintLayout` inside `LinearLayout`. I just had to explicitly add `LayoutParams` while adding my view.

```
override fun setContentView(view: View?) {
    val toolbar = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_toolbar, null, false)
    titleView = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView

    val finalView = LinearLayout(this)
    finalView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    finalView.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    finalView.addView(toolbar)
    finalView.addView(view, LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
    super.setContentView(finalView)
}
```

Comment: for me I was missing orientation